# Mysql Subquery order by date(remove duplicate)

Tags: mysql

```
tableName : account

date    name
2016-05 john
2016-05 bob
2016-05 kate
2016-06 jake
2016-06 billy
```

result is

```
2016-05  john, bob, kate
2016-06  jake, billy
```

i am trying this

```
select date,(select name from account where date ??? )
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `date` and use `group_concat` to get a list of names for each date

```
select date, group_concat(name)
from account
group by date
```

If needed you can also specify a seperator and even an order like this

```
group_concat(name separator ', ' order by name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group_Concat

```
select date,group_concat(name) 
 from account  Group by Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate names which may occur on a given date then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`:

```
SELECT date, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name)
FROM account
GROUP BY date
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle